# IO values into haskell function

Tags: haskell, io

I currently have a function with definition:

```
f :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
```

And have two variables of type IO [Int] and IO Int. I want to pass these variables to this function f. I am able to do this when it is just one variable being passed to the function, but when it is 2 I can't get it to work.

Comment: A value in a variable of type IO Int is a thing you can do to get an Int. For example "let the user type in a number" is a value of type IO Int. You cannot calculate "let the user type in a number" + "pick a random number". You have to let the user type in a number, then pick a random number, then calculate the first number + the second number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `<-` in `do` notation and run the function on the unwrapped values.

```hs
-- Implementations left out
xsFn :: IO [Int]
xFn :: IO Int

main = do
  xs <- xsFn
  x <- xFn
  -- We've unwrapped the values, so now xs :: [Int] and x :: Int

  let result = f xs x -- result :: [[Int]]
  -- do something with result
  return ()
```

Answer (score 12):

You can write a `do` block:

```
f' :: IO [[Int]]
f' = do
    x <- val1
    y <- val2
    return (f x y)
```

with `val1 :: IO [Int]` and `val2 :: IO Int` the values you want to pass as parameters.

or in an applicative style:

```
f' :: IO [[Int]]
f' = f <$> val1 <*> val2
```

or we can make use of [**`liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2):

```
f' :: IO [[Int]]
f' = liftA2 f val1 val2
```

Answer (score 2):

`IO` has an `Applicative` instance, so you can use `liftA2`:

```
> f = undefined :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
> import Control.Applicative
> :t liftA2 f
liftA2 f :: Applicative f => f [Int] -> f Int -> f [[Int]]
```

With the `TypeApplications` extension, you can see it more clearly.

```
> :set -XTypeApplications
> :t liftA2 @IO f
liftA2 @IO f :: IO [Int] -> IO Int -> IO [[Int]]
```